# How to include ValidationError.CustomState in ResponseStatus.Meta?

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

I have the following code in one of my validators:

```
        RuleFor(foo => foo)
            .Must(foo => foo != null)
            .WithState(bar => new { Baz, Qux });
```

Then in my service I have this:

```
        var validationResult = new FooValidator().Validate(req.Foo);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            throw validationResult.ToException();
        }
```

I thought the CustomState of the ValidationError would be included in the ResponseStatus.Meta property. However, that was not the case.

Is there a clean way I can make this happen?

Comment: Can you update your question with a link to the docs/content that your assumed behavior is based on?

Comment: I think I just assumed that it would work, being used to ServiceStack's versatility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously ServiceStack only supported maintaining a String Dictionary state which would be serialized under the ResponseStatus **Error Field** `Meta` Dictionary, e.g:

```
RuleFor(foo => foo)
    .Must(foo => foo != null)
    .WithState(bar => new Dictionary<string,string> { ["Baz"] = "Qux" });
```

Which will be serialized in the **Error Field** `Meta` dictionary, e.g:

```
response.Errors[0].Meta //= ["Bar"] = "Qux"
```

This is the preferred approach as the same `Dictionary<string,string>` configured in your CustomState will be serialized as-is in the `Meta` dictionary.

Otherwise I've just added support for anonymous objects so you're now able to use:

```
RuleFor(foo => foo)
    .Must(foo => foo != null)
    .WithState(bar => new { Baz = "Qux" });
```

Which will result in the same serialized response DTO.

This change is available from v5.9.3+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).